# Probleme with structure, string anf gtkwidget

Tags: c, string, struct, gtk

I'm trying to create a diaporama in c using gtk. I have a button "previous", which show the previous image. So I connect my button to a function and I pass it to a structure. But when I try to print an element of my array I have weird characters, and I don't know why. Plus, I got this warning for my gtk image :

```
GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 19:12:16.442: invalid uninstantiatable type '(null)' in cast to 'GtkImage'
Gtk-CRITICAL **: 19:12:16.442: IA__gtk_image_set_from_file: assertion 'GTK_IS_IMAGE (image)' failed
```

Here's my structure :

```
struct ButtonsArg {
    GtkWidget *image;
    char *img[];
};
```

Here's my code for the initialisation of my structure in the main :

```
GtkWidget *image = gtk_image_new();

char *images[nbImages];
//I get the name of all my image in this function
getImageList(images);

//This print work fine
printf("%s\n", images[0]);


struct ButtonsArg * arg;

arg = malloc(sizeof(struct ButtonsArg) + nbImages*sizeof(char*));

for(int i = 0; i < nbImages; i++) {
    arg->img[i] = malloc(strlen(images[i])+1);
    strcpy(arg->img[i], images[i]);
}

arg->image = image;

g_signal_connect(precedent, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(event_precedent), &arg);
```

Here's the function where the problems occur:

```
static void event_previous(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data) {
    g_print ("previous\n");
    struct ButtonsArg *arg = data;

    //Print weird charac
    for(int i = 0; i < nbImages; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", arg->img[i]);
    }

    GtkWidget *image = arg->image;

    if(currentImage == 0) {
        currentImage = nbImages - 1;
         gtk_image_set_from_file (GTK_IMAGE (arg->image), arg->img[1]);
    } else {
        currentImage--;
        gtk_image_set_from_file (GTK_IMAGE (arg->image), arg->img[2]);
    }
}
```

If you have any advice, help or link that could help, thanks for sharing it with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show the part of code where you try to change GtkImage variable? Seems like program was trying to set the null-value to GtkImage-type variable. In this cause any expression with this variable (like image->value) can raise segementation fault.

UPD: Ok. I see it. You should be check the arg-structure. I think, some attribute of this structure can have null-value.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't know why, I set it, and even if I do a check with a 
    if(image == NULL) {
        printf("null");
    }
no message is print

Comment: Sometimes NULL-value comparing is not working properly. Can you use the GDB? Set the breakpoint to this line " struct ButtonsArg *arg = data;" and in debugger window type the "arg->image". What the value you get?

Comment: In adding, can you show the part of code where is the function "event_previous" is used? I want to be sure which the data you will set as "gpointer data" argument.

Comment: When I try to print it, the debugger say : "Cannot access memory at adress 0x0"
And I add the line, it's in the main, in the function g_signal_connect

Comment: This is the good sign. How can you see, the value of "arg->image" is zero, but in the same way not be equal NULL. This is why youre if-statement is not working here. Well, you need to be sure what the value you trying to send into event-handler as "data". Especially the attribute 'image".



UPD: Oh, do you jumped to next line from "struct ButtonArg *arg = data" before you try to print the "arg->image"-value?

Comment: Ah no, I put the breakpoint exactly on the line, but I just change it, and the message change :
"$3 = 0x555555867dc0

Comment: Looks like the problem with arg->img arrays, that contained the filenames of pictures. So, can you print the "arg->img[1] ", "arg->img[2] " & "arg->img" by GDB?

Comment: When I do that without debugger I get weird character anf with the debugger :
    $4 = 0x555555844050 "\340M\201UUU"
    $5 = 0x555555848800 "\240\361\203UUU"
for arg->img[0] and arg->img[1]

Comment: In documentation about  gtk_image_set_from_file function says that second arguments is a filename-string, that stored in gchar-type. Maybe, you should change the char-type in ButtonsArg-structure to gchar-type. Try it. And make shure the filename of picture is not containing any non-ASCII symbols.

Comment: It work with a classic char, I'm already showing an image add the end of the main, so I don't think that it

Comment: `g_signal_connect(precedent, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(event_precedent), &arg);` -- is that the intialize of event-handler "event_previous"? If  is that true, instead `&arg` you need to write `arg`. In documentation `gpointer` is a `typedef` of `void *`.

Comment: I think it come from the way I init my struct with my char array

Comment: `&arg` instead `arg`? I want to be sure, maybe it will be helpful for me :)

Comment: Yes, just that :D